# Marshalling a float[][] as float**

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

Let's say I have a C++ function with the prototype

```
int someFunction(const float ** raws)
```

How can I call this function with a `float[][]` argument from C#? Possibly without using unsafe code.

Comment: A `float[][]` is fundamentally different to a `float **`, so probably not.

Comment: Well it shouldn't be impossible. I'm sure there's a way. That's why I called it "marshalling".

Comment: I mean a hack way of doing it is to put the float[][] into a class/struct and just pass that around instead.

Comment: Passing it around by reference specifically, so that you don't duplicate the entire float[][] on the stack every time you pass it into a function.

Comment: Kind of figured that was implied, as long as with adding correct wrapping on the data within the class/struct

Comment: It can be a float[][] or a float[,].  No way to tell from the declaration, C arrays are hopelessly ambiguous.  You would not know what to pass from a C program either.  Ignore the comment about passing by ref, arrays already are reference types.

Comment: @hattenn sure. Use manual marshalling to make new arrays in the memory.

Comment: What about creating a root array of `float*[]`, copying the addresses of first items in actual arrays, and passing `&array`?

Comment: @RoadBump I think it would be a solution, but I'd really appreciate a way without unsafe code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know you have to do most of the work yourself. Interop will help you with marshalling the top-level array, but it's going to be your job to pin all the nested arrays, and then unpin them when you're done. This code shows one way to do that:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ManagedClient
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("UnmanagedDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int UseFloats([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] IntPtr[] raws);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float[][] data =
            {
                new[] { 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f },
                new[] { 1.0f, 1.1f, 1.2f, 1.3f },
                new[] { 2.0f },
                new[] { 3.0f, 3.1f }
            };

            var handles = new GCHandle[data.Length];
            var pointers = new IntPtr[data.Length];

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
                {
                    var h = GCHandle.Alloc(data[i], GCHandleType.Pinned);
                    handles[i] = h;
                    pointers[i] = h.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                }

                UseFloats(pointers);
            }
            finally
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < handles.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if (handles[i].IsAllocated)
                    {
                        handles[i].Free();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This builds an array of pointers, each of which points to the `float` data in the input arrays. (That's the format that your C function expects the data to arrive in.) How your C code knows the length of each of those subarrays is up to you. In my test code I just hard-coded it to match what the C# code passed in:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall UseFloats(const float ** raws) 
{
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n", raws[0][0], raws[0][1], raws[0][2], raws[0][3], raws[0][4]);
    printf("%f %f %f %f\n", raws[1][0], raws[1][1], raws[1][2], raws[1][3], raws[0][4]);
    printf("%f\n", raws[2][0]);
    printf("%f %f\n", raws[3][0], raws[3][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

In reality you're probably going to want to do something to tell the unmanaged code how long each of the subarrays is - the unmanaged function signature you've chosen doesn't give the called code any way of knowing each subarray's length. (Presumably the reason you're using float** is because you want jagged arrays. If not, and if each subarray is exactly the same length, it'd be a whole lot more efficient to use rectangular arrays here instead of an array of pointers, and it would make the marshalling easier too.)

Comment: Good answer. You probably meant "Presumably the reason you're using float[][]" not "float**" and that should be underlined or bolded because if that is the case two dimensional arrays (float[,]) can be marshaled automatically.

Comment: Thanks! But I meant what I wrote: I blamed "float**" because that's the signature of the unmanaged function he's trying to call. That's the signature that's the root cause of the trouble. (Switching to float[,] in C# wouldn't help you much if the unmanaged signature continues to be float** - that unmanaged signature requires an array of pointers, which is the heart of the problem. Starting with float[,] would mean you'd only need to pin one object, but you'd still need to build an IntPtr[].) I think the best solution would be to change the unmanaged signature, if possible.

Comment: @Ian Why do you use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]`? And also, what is the default marshalling if you don't use that attribute?

Comment: I used that because I knew the unmanaged side required the array to be passed in the C style, i.e., as a pointer to the first element. I can't remember what the default is, and when I use P/Invoke I prefer to be explicit to make sure I'm getting what I mean, rather than relying on the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Ian already answered your question, I'd only like to suggest using SAFEARRAY on the C++ side.

SAFEARRAY are the COM answer to the problem of ambiguous array definitions in C/C++, they are structures which contain the number and size of the underlying elements and are a better match for .Net arrays. Using them would allow automatic marshaling of the array from C#.

SAFEARRAY are painful to work with in C++ but ATL has some nice wrappers to make things easier. If at all possible change the C++ function to use it or consider writing a C++ wrapper for interop with .Net that uses them and has the marshaling code written in C++.

Comment: Unfortunately, the C++ code is written by someone else and I don't have much control over it. Appreciate the suggestion though!